# What's a better way to combine two fields before saving to db in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I have to select a date and a time for something. I'm using `simple_form`, and twitter bootstrap with the `datepicker` and `timepicker` gems.

First, I wasn't able to customize the form generators enough to get everything to work, so in my view i have, hardcoded:

```
<div class="control-group string optional">
          <label class="string optional control-label" for="publish_day">Publish Date</label>
          <div class="controls">
            <div class="input-append date" id="publish_date" data-date="<%= @press_release.published_day %>" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
              <input class="span2" type="text" name="press_release[publish_day]" value="<%= @press_release.published_day %>" readonly>
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

       <div class="control-group string optional">
          <label class="string optional control-label" for="publish_time">Publish Time</label>
          <div class="controls">  
            <div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker-component date">
              <input class="span2" id="publish_time" name="press_release[publish_time]" type="text" readonly>
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

which is lame, and probably not 'correct', but i don't know how to customize simple_form enough to get it to do that for me.

Second, to combine the fields to add to the database, here's what i'm doing in the controller:

```
params[:press_release][:publish_date] = Time.parse("#{params[:press_release][:publish_day]} #{params[:press_release][:publish_time]}")
```

which is seems really hacky, but i can't figure out another way to do it. what's a better way to take data from two forms fields and then combine and format it? i'm guessing it's something with before_save but i don't know how to pass the `params` to a method called that way.

any suggestions are appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

One improvement you can make is to move the parsing/formatting to the `PressRelease` model.

```
attr_accessor :publish_day, :publish_time

before_validate do
  self.publish_date = Time.parse([self.publish_day, self.publish_time].join(" ")) if self.publish_day.present?
end
```

This way you keep the reassignment of the `params` values out of the controller *(you're right, it does look 'hacky')*

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to go back to your view and try to get it working with 'rails fields.
I would not worry about the controller and concatenating the two fields together, I actually think that approach is a pretty good solution.

So I would look at the form and try and get the date and time fields 'railsy'

Here's my field from one of my apps with a date picker on the field too:

```
   = f.text_field :content_date, id: 'datepicker', size: 10
```

If you have errors with this approach please post the specific errors you are getting plus the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment so I'll post here.

```
attr_accessor :publish_day, :publish_time

before_validation do
  self.publish_date = Time.parse([self.publish_day, self.publish_time].join(" ")) if self.publish_day.present?
end
```